# How to incremental a variable and while in a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I have a `.each` loop that iterates over some data and for each item in the data set it appends a span class to the `DOM`.

`$('.selected_cont').append('<span class="' + classes + '"></span>');`

Classes is just the variable ive creative above that saves the name of the data I iterate over.

So after iterating over the data I could have 5, 10 `span` tags on the `DOM` all with different class names.

My issue is, I don't add the `span` tags in the order they're in the data so the latest one ive iterated over will be the first.

So I've created a variable

var incrementalEle = 1;

How can I add this variable into my string `$('.selected_cont').append('<span class="' + classes + '"></span>');` so each `class` has something similar to `theClassName1`, `theClassName2` and so on.

This errors when I try it `$('.selected_cont').append('<span class="' + classes + + var incrementalEle++ + '"></span>');`

Comment: @Satpal how would I add a space between the word in the class name and the variable incremental so the class name would be something like `firstClassname selected1`

Comment: Too add space `$('.selected_emoji').append('<span class="' + classes + '  ' +incrementalEle++ + '"></span>')`, I would recommend you to use `.addClass()`

Comment: @Satpal i've got this `$('.selected_emoji').append('<span class="' + classes + '' + 'test' + +incrementalEle++ + '"></span>')` but in the `DOM` i'm getting `theClasstest1` and `theClasstest1` it isn't incrementing for some reason and the space isn't being added

Comment: It would be better if you show the complete code.

Comment: @Satpal it's fine. I missunderstood what i'm doing. I thought within my `each` loop each iteration I could increment however, I just read all the data and spit elements into the `DOM` depending on the items in the data so there's no room to iterate because it just happens once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery to create element, use `.addClass()` method at set the classes.

```
$('.selected_emoji').append($('<span />').addClass(classes + incrementalEle++ ));
```

OR, when using string concatenation use operator's properly

```
$('.selected_emoji').append('<span class="' + classes + incrementalEle++ + '"></span>')
```